# How to Dynamically Add a Class to HTML Tag by Template in WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, function

I want to add a background image to the HTML of just the default page.php and the best way would be to have a class on the HTML tag so that I could target that in the css so ideally I want to say "If is this page template, add a class of 'header-default' to the HTML tag"

I have tried researching and I got something like this cobbled together but really need some specific direction:

```
function is_page_template( $template = 'page.php' ) {

    if ( is_page_template( $template ) ) {
        if ( ( in_array( 'default', $template, true ) && ! $page_template )
            'html' => 'page--header__default',
        ) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return ( 'default' === $template && ! $page_template );
}
```

I am receiving an error that the syntax is wrong by js is not my strong suite so i have no idea what the idea what the issue is.

Comment: This is not **JS**, this is **PHP**. Wordpress is written in PHP (some would say that not entirely :) ). If you see `$variable` ( **$** sign before a variable), then it's PHP (or some jQuery stuff, if you work with Wordpress, at least).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to add class to HTML tag. You need to add it to body. WordPress already have a filter that allows you to set custom class, please check the following example:

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'custom_class' );
function custom_class( $classes ) {
    if ( is_page_template( 'page-example.php' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'example';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Source: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/#comment-1846